# Php/Jquery/Ajax: On Accordian Click, it loads content within the page within Accordian

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I currently created a page full of information from our database which currently connects to two databases using php, javascript, jquery.  I need to make the page upload faster.  I have some information displaying right away and some information hidden on the page by use of an accordion / tab.  What I would like to do is only load the information that is shown at first.  When the user wants more information, they will click on the accordion tab and then the information will then, and only then, be upload within the page (again trying to save upload time).

Here is an example of one of my accordion tabs...

```
    <div class='expand_container3' style='float:left; margin-top:10px; width:100%;'>
        <div class='expand_header3' style='width:100%; text-transform:uppercase;' > <span>+ Archives</span> </div><div class='expand_content3' style='width:100%; margin:auto;'>
            <table  class='license_table arch_tab' style='border:1px solid #222; width:100%;'>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Archive Number</th>
                    <th>Arichive Date</th>
                    <th>Install Archive</th>
                    <th>Renewal Archive</th>
                    <th>Mailed Archive</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php echo $archiverow ?>
                <tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div >
    <script>
        $(".expand_header3").click(function () {

            $expand_header3 = $(this);
            //getting the next element
            $expand_content3 = $expand_header3.next();
            //open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
            $expand_content3.slideToggle(500, function () {
                //execute this after slideToggle is done
                //change text of header based on visibility of content div
                $expand_header3.text(function () {
                    //change text based on condition
                    return $expand_content3.is(":visible") ? " -  Archives " : " +  Archives ";
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
```

So again, I don't want the content to be upload during the first page load, but when they click on the accordion tab, it uploads the content within the div. Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to create different files with the content of each tab, then on each tab link onclick event use jquery('#').load(), to load the content only when the tab is select.

Are you using plane old php or a PHP framework? Which?

Comment: Just plain ole' Php...   Creating a template page in wordpress.

Comment: If were to do the  jquery('#').load(), could we load a page like page.php (a php page in it?)

Comment: Sorry for delay. In the case of wordpress you have to create the page and register it on the dashboard. Remember you can override page by creating a file in your theme named "page-{slug}.php"

Comment: You could also (better yet) create a little ajax php functions that look up the data you need for each tab and then make jquery().get to obtain the data. Remember that if for public view you have to register the ajax function in both admin and no-admin.